Is there a limit to the number of times a journal editor will send my paper for review if referees keep declining?
I submitted a paper to Physical Review D, an APS journal, approximately a month ago. So far, the editor has forwarded my paper to six referees for review, all of whom have declined. I suspect this may be due to the summer break. My paper is a concise six pages long and I find it to be interesting. I am eager to learn about the next steps in this process. Is there a limit to the number of times the editor will send my paper to referees for review?

Editor here. There's a point where if everyone you ask declines to review the paper, you come to conclude that one of two possibilities must be the case: (i) the people you asked looked at the paper and thought it was a waste of their time, (ii) the people you asked had no idea of the topic and did not think they are qualified. More often than not, it's (ii). The conclusion you draw as an editor is that if you, too, don't know the area well enough to find the right people, then the paper is not within the scope of the journal: If you don't know the area, and the people you ask to review the paper don't know the area, then the area is not well represented by who (you think) the readership of the journal is. So you decline the paper as "out of scope".
For me, at six people declining, I would already give up on the paper unless the majority of these people wrote to me with good reasons for declining, and perhaps nominating others.

Comparing your answer with the other one, I guess there may be a difference between math and physics.

@Kimball Possibly. Though in reality, I suspect that after 6 refusals to review, editors in other disciplines also give up. I do not believe that people's willingness to review a paper in their field is noticeably different between fields -- in parts because I've never heard anyone make such a claim.

Could there be a difference in terms of how many decline due to not "having time to provide a timely report"?

From my experience as editor, six reviewers declining to review is by no means a large number. The problem is exaggerated if the journals requires two reviews (I don't know about the practice at Phys Rev D). Usually, there is no upper limit, but if they cannot find reviewers even after a long time (6-12 months), the editor may decide to give up and decline the paper on the basis that they cannot find reviewers.
If you are worried about a delay to publication, you could post it on the arXiv now.

"If you are worried about a delay to publication, you could post it on the arXiv now (unless you're not sure it will pass peer review)." If you are not confident enough in a paper to go to on the arxiv, you should not send it for peer review. What you are suggesting here is a rather unethical waste of reviewer/editor time.

(Note that if the paper is not on arxiv, this can be one reason for potential reviewers declining the review.)

@TimRias You can see the full paper in APS' referee portal before accepting to review, so declining just because it isn't on arXiv (yet) would be a bit weird and overreaching, IMO.

@Anyon There is actually a number of good reasons for doing so. One of them being the apparent lack of faith that authors have in their paper.

Thanks for the answer and comments. PRD requires one review for our paper. If my paper is not reviewed by PRD after being published on arXiv, I may need to consider submitting it to another journal. However, if the next reviewer sees that the paper has been on arXiv for an extended period of time (e.g. 1 or 2 months), they may assume that there are unresolved issues with the paper that have prevented it from being accepted in previous reviews. Hence I prefer not to publish my work on arXiv unless being accepted.

No reasonable person will decline to review a paper just because it is not posted as a preprint on arXiv. There is no formal or informal requirement that people post their papers there. Why would a reviewer feel like such a requirement should be enforced?

@TimRias I agree with your first comment and have removed the offending "(unless you're not sure it will pass peer review)".  However, I disagree with your second comment.

@WolfgangBangerth Many reasonable people (that value their time) do.

@TimRias This makes no sense to me. What reason would they have? Why would a reviewer insist on a paper being posted to a preprint server? Posting a preprint is not an indication of quality or any other property of the paper a reviewer may be interested in. I don't buy your argument that posting a paper on a preprint server is a statement by the authors that they have faith in the correctness or importance of the paper.

@WolfgangBangerth I think the key element you are missing is that in the subject areas that PRD serves, arXiv is the defacto primary way that research is disseminated to peers. So, the question to ask is what reasons can authors have to delay disseminating their results? None of the answers to that question bode well for the quality of the manuscript. There are various practical reasons as well, but this is not the place to discuss them.

@TimRias I posted a separate question about these reasons https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/212321/17254 Hope to see your perspective fleshed out more in the form of answers there.
