What are good reasons for declining to referee a manuscript that hasn't been posted on arXiv?
This question is inspired by the comments under this answer, specifically the points raised by user TimRias. The discussion was about a paper submitted to Physical Review D (PRD), a journal covering the physics related to particles, fields, gravitation, and cosmology. This is a field where posting a preprint to arXiv is extremely common. The relevant comments read in relevant part:

(Note that if the paper is not on arxiv, this can be one reason for potential reviewers declining the review.)


There is actually a number of good reasons for doing so. One of them being the apparent lack of faith that authors have in their paper


in the subject areas that PRD serves, arXiv is the defacto primary way that research is disseminated to peers. So, the question to ask is what reasons can authors have to delay disseminating their results? None of the answers to that question bode well for the quality of the manuscript.  There are various practical reasons as well

Question: What are these good reasons for declining invitations to review papers that have not been posted on arXiv?
Note 1: Clearly, this question only makes sense in the context of fields where posting to arXiv is prevalent enough to be the default. Answers from fields where this does not hold true are very unlikely to be useful.
Note 2: The journal in question has an online referee portal through which one can read the full manuscript before accepting or declining.

My own perspective is from condensed matter physics, which also makes heavy use of arXiv, though I don't think it's quite as prevalent as in particle physics because the field also overlaps with chemistry, materials science etc. I've had (predominantly experimentalist) coauthors request holding off on posting a preprint, not because of a lack of confidence in the results (indeed, these papers were often submitted to the glossy journals), but out of a concern for scooping. It also seems somewhat weird to me to conclude that the absence of a posted preprint necessarily implies lack of confidence - perhaps it was submitted to arXiv but just misclassified and got stuck in moderation... Overall, it seems like referees acting as described above could potentially give the arXiv moderators a lot of power that they didn't ask for.

Do you mean to say that experimental physicists are more concerned about being scooped than theoretical physicists? That is peculiar, I would have expected the opposite: it's much easier to scoop a bunch of equations and computations than to repeat an experiment that took months and complicated infrastructure to perform.

How would getting an exact timestamp for when the paper was completed make it easier to scoop?

@FedericoPoloni That is indeed my impression - publishing in experimental physics is higher stakes to some extent. More important to get into fancy journals (where the publication process often is slooow) to get jobs etc. That said, the concern seems almost inversely proportional to the time it takes to conduct the experiments. After claims of new superconductors you often see groups rushing to grow samples and get some preliminary results within weeks. Of course, that scenario likely doesn't translate well into the types of experiments that might get published in PRD.

@TobiasKildetoft In practice in my field, the citations are highly affected by which paper was published in a journal first. This means that there have been instances of someone hearing about a significant result, rushing to reproduce it, and then getting it rapidly published in say Physical Review B while the original paper is struggling with reviews in say Nature Physics. If we had a policy that everything gets posted to arXiv first, perhaps that timestamp would be viewed as more significant.

I have served as an editor/managing editor of three math journals and in this capacity was involved in refereeing process of countless papers. Many, but not all, mathematicians post their preprints on the arXiv. Not a single time a potential referee declined refereeing a paper because it was not posted on the arXiv. I think, there is a good chance you are asking about something that simply does not exist.

If arXiv posting is the default method in a subfield, then it's also the way people claim priority. There's no reason to worry about getting "scooped" after posting on arXiv.

@TobiasKildetoft, knzhou: At least in math, I agree that posting result X to the arXiv gives you priority for result X.  But maybe you only proved that to use for result Y, which you're still working on, so maybe you want to wait, e.g., to post both papers at the same time.  I don't know how common this is, but at least in principle I can see it happening sometimes.

@MoisheKohan This might be very field-specific; Arxiv is much more widespread in (some areas of) physics than in mathematics, from what I hear.

A couple of answers to Why do some journals want to send the manuscript to arXiv before submission? partially address my question: 1 and 2.

In my view this would be downright unethical.
If you don't have time to review, just say so. If the title and abstract aren't interesting to you, decline on that basis. Nobody's making you review it, so don't bother with some nonsensical justification.
The task of the reviewer is to assess the written paper as submitted, not to speculate on the confidence of the authors. Maybe they lack confidence because the results are so unexpected? This all comes across as a way to put down novel results and keep outsiders out. Refusing to review on this basis seems a rather dishonest way of reviewing - i.e. of signalling your opinion of the unworthiness of the paper to the journal - while disclaiming responsibility.
Worse, the putative reviewer doesn't actually know this about the authors: they are just speculating on the basis that they've not found an OA preprint.
There's an insulting undertone there: not everyone has an easy route to getting an arXiv endorsement, is willing to deal with the hassle of non-standard licenses, or has the energy to deal with the extra bureaucracy around IP and dissemination issues in their particular organisation. There are many valid reasons for not having a preprint in the arXiv, and dissing papers on this basis is IMO both wrong and dishonest.
There's also the rather weird situation around arXiv becoming the de facto gatekeeper to publishing for an entire field: who elected them? (arXiv may be widely used in a field as a repository, but here it's suddenly instead being used as a filter.)
(Elsewhere, there would also be concerns about double-blind reviews)
Disclaimer: PRD may not be my usual field, but I'm a named (i.e. non-corresponding) author on at least one (OA) PRD paper, as well as a number of others for which preprints have been posted in arXiv. I don't have an arXiv account.

To take a slightly different angle at this: Even if the authors did not publish a preprint on account of some unfounded fear of being scooped, having an embarrassing first version, a complex submission process, or whatever, “educating” them by not reviewing their paper is unlikely to even reach them (will the editor tell the authors that potential reviewers refused because they did not a preprint?) and even less likely to work.

Another scenario I considered mentioning in the question is: what about authors banned by arXiv? If they're banned for posting unscientific garbage, perhaps it's not much of a loss if their papers aren't reviewed. But there have also been at least one temporary ban for unprofessional language. The linked story was in the context of pointing out scientific fraud, so it would be particularly problematic if arXiv could suppress such criticism from the literature.

Lou, could you please re-read your third paragraph and fix the first sentence?

@Anyon An aspect that I'd like to expand on at some point (but need to find good words) is that (summary!) there is an underlying assumption that everyone is in academia - a lot of this stuff suddenly isn't that easy for industrial/commercial or even govt. labs. Maybe people will argue that PRD doesn't publish such research, but maybe that's precisely because it dissuades it...

My former supervisor often uploaded his papers to the arXiv post-publication because he was often spammed by various people asking their works to be cited in the published version. This is not always unreasonable, but for the most part this was "give publicity to my mostly  irrelevant (to the paper at hand, at least) results pls", and he simply didn't want to deal with this. Just another example if why someone would not want to pre-publish to the arXiv.

"If you don't have time to review, just say so. If the title and abstract aren't interesting to you, decline on that basis. Nobody's making you review it, so don't bother with some nonsensical justification." Nobody has time to review. Everybody has to make time to review.  Consequently, everybody needs some way to decide which papers to make time for and which not. I actually consider it quite ethical to do this one basis of indicators that correlate strongly with authors wasting reviewers time.

"Maybe they lack confidence because the results are so unexpected?" Why would that ever be a reason not to post the preprint? I would consider the use of peer reviewer to filter a possible bad result,  an example of unethical use of peer reviewer time.

@TimRias: I would consider the use of peer reviewer to filter a possible bad result, an example of unethical use of peer reviewer time. – But that’s one of the main purposes of peer review. Of course, authors should investigate unexpected results to an appropriate extent, but at some point they have to move to peer review (while acknowledging that they are unexpected).

@Wrzlprmft Yes, and they should only move to that point, we’re the manuscript has reached the stage where they would not be embarrassed by it, if someone points out a short coming in the result during peer review.

I feel like this asks the wrong question.
Referees can decline to review for any reason. They do not need a "good" reason to refuse to review. Therefore, if a referee does not want to review a paper that's not on the arXiv, that's their prerogative. Granted you could argue that "because it's not on the arXiv" is a bad reason to decline to review a paper, but it's still their prerogative. Nobody can make them review a paper (see e.g. this question).
Given that, we could answer peripheral questions:

Is it common? No. I vaguely remember seeing it once, with the reviewer saying that they want to see the paper before agreeing to review it, and they couldn't find it on the arXiv.
Is it a good reason? That's dependent on one's personal values. See this comment for another reason to decline that different people will call good/not good.
Is it acceptable? Yes, because it's their prerogative. If the decline reason goes against your personal values, then it can be aggravating, and it might color one's impression of the reviewer. But then a lot of things can do it too (such as whether they review a paper on autonomous armed drones, or travel to lots of conferences building up a giant carbon footprint, etc.).
What does the editor do next? If the underlying reason is because they want to see the manuscript before agreeing to review (as in first bullet point), then one might send them the paper (not always possible because of confidentiality requirements). Otherwise, there's always the option of finding another reviewer.

But there is not likely to be a broad-based consensus opinion on what these good reasons are.

I'm interested in what the referees acting in this way consider "good reasons". Given the apparent field-specificity I don't expect there to be a broad consensus supporting those reasons.

Unfortunately people will consider their own reasons to be "good reasons", just as I obviously consider my objections to be "good" objections. Others will disagree! The issue is whether some wider community (e.g. the field, or academia, or all scientists) sees them as good reasons. Possibly a danger with field-specificity is that it can normalise poor behaviour as people go with what's usual around them, rather than stepping back?

Good reason: If you believe every paper in your field should be posted to arXiv, then refusing to review papers that are not posted there puts some pressure on authors to post there.
Reasons for that reason may be varied but likely includes reducing the reliance on the more traditional academic publishing pipeline which is primarily run for-profit. arXiv ensures work is not entirely behind a paywall and facilitates rapid communication of results to the field.

What's the justification for you demanding ("put pressure") that authors waste our time putting preprints on arXiv? Especially when the Version of Record will itself be Open Access?

@LouKnee I'm just giving a reason, not saying that I do this. If someone agrees with my reason, they'd disagree with you that it's a waste of time. And even if the final version is open access, in the meantime the results are secret. Also, I'm not in a field that uses arxiv but the preprint servers I've experienced have been pretty painless to submit to besides the tedium of documenting coauthor affiliations.

sorry to be coming across as a bit bolshy, but something underlying this question makes me very uncomfortable... If refusing-to-review is a good way to "put pressure", this just shifts the question to why "putting pressure" is good. The results aren't even necessarily secret - they may already be out there as a bunch of conference posters for example. The preprint being demanded is by definition close to the form and content of the intended article.

@LouKnee "If refusing-to-review is a good way to "put pressure", this just shifts the question to why "putting pressure" is good" - exactly, that's why my answer has two paragraphs. The second paragraph answers the shifted question of why putting pressure might be seen as good.

Maybe, but I don't think the arXiv-specificness of our hypothetical reviewer candidate is a appropriate way to achieve those goals.
(got to stop there for tonight)

@LouKnee As OP noted, the entire premise here only makes sense for those fields which already use arXiv heavily.

I think it is fair to only "gift work to" (i.e. review) papers, which also give back to the community by being open access. So I like this argument with the caveat that arxiv is not the only means to achieve this goal, but a very common one.

I don't mind arXiv being the preferred repository within a field: "I just posted my preprint about X" "Ooh, I'll take a look" [knows where to look]. The trouble is that the premise of the question both changes its status from "preferred" to "mandatory", and changes its role from repository to gatekeeper - that's where my objections kick in.

"more traditional academic publishing pipeline which is primarily run for-profit." better to fix the problem rather than abandon proper peer review.  Journals can be run on a not-for-profit basis, the only reason it doesn't happen more is that academics don't make the effort to make it happen often enough (c.f. jmlr.org which demonstrates how well it can work).  Pressuring others seems to be making it someone else's problem rather than dealing with something you don't like yourself.

@DikranMarsupial I think there is a mistaken tendency to believe that any solutions that don't entirely fix a problem or are not the best fix are automatically not worth it. The comparison should be to the status quo, not the ideal. A reviewer could put even more weight on the scales by refusing entirely to review for a for profit journal, but one who acknowledges that this is still the norm might see preprints as far better than no preprints.

@DikranMarsupial I strongly disagree that this is making it "someone else's problem"; it's a reviewer exerting the influence that they, individually, have in the system.

@BryanKrause I am in favour of arXiv, but until arXiv is fully peer reviewed, it is not fixing the problem.  " it's a reviewer exerting the influence that they, individually" it is the reviewer pushing a political agenda.  In this case it is one that I happen to agree with (it wastes a lot of tax payers money), but if pushing this particular political agenda is O.K. how do we decide which political agendas are O.K. for the reviewer to push and which are not?

Refereeing a paper not on the arxiv can result in some awkwardness if one wants to use ideas from the paper or build on their work. One has to then wait until the paper is officially published before one can do so in order to ethically keep one's role anonymous. In contrast, if there is an arxiv version, one can immediately cite that and build on that without any worry that they will detect if one was a referee.

But would this be a good reason to decline reviewing a paper?

This somehow gives me a bit of an icky feeling... Like, I get how this is a benefit in general, but is it actually a good reason to decline reviewing? I'm also concerned with the conflict-of-interest possibilities of building on a paper you're reviewing during the review process. Might a reviewer, intentionally or not, be more critical of a result they're improving on the side, such that they might submit their own work somewhere while the original is still in review (either with that journal or another one)?

@WolfgangBangerth Yes, in so far as (at least in math) the process involved in thinking about a paper one is refereeing in a hard enough way to do a good review means one will be at some point thinking hard enough about the topic that one is likely to see other avenues later about it.

@BryanKrause I'm not sure one will be more critical. If anything, I'd expect it to make one less critical since one wants the editors to then accept that paper. I also wouldn't see it as likely for someone to build on a paper while they are reviewing (which I agree creates some definite issues), but that there are often months between when one referees a paper to when it gets published. That means that in that intervening time, the ideas from that paper may be repeatedly bouncing around one's head.

@JoshuaZ but then without the public preprint you will have fewer competitors and more time to follow up those other avenues, so I can't see why you think this is a good reason to decline to review - surely it's to your (personal) benefit?

@LouKnee Definitely to one's personal benefit. But it potentially creates a complicated, awkward situation. So a reasonable thing to do is just avoid the whole thing.

Are you able to move fast enough in your field to have a paper out before peer review is done?

@Azor, depends on the paper and how long the editors take. I know this has been an issue for other mathematicians. I myself am not that fast generally.

" I'd expect it to make one less critical since one wants the editors to then accept that paper." I would view that as equally unethical as it means the reviewers personal gain is affecting their judgement.  "That means that in that intervening time, the ideas from that paper may be repeatedly bouncing around one's head" in my experience allowing ideas to do that for quite a long time is generally a good thing.

@LouKnee Precisely for that reason is working on such avenues before the work is public highly unethical. No such objections exist if the work is already public at the time of review.

The other answers give good reasons -- it supports open science and it avoids confidentiality issues.
An additional reason is that a paper being on arxiv may actually be a mark of quality. At the very least this means the authors think the work is ready to be published and are happy to have their names attached to it publicly. In other words, a paper not being on arxiv could be a sign that the authors don't think it is ready.
A problem in my field (computer science) is that many papers are written in a great rush for the submission deadline, and it shows. Papers that are on arxiv are usually a bit more polished than such last minute submissions. Reviewers don't want to waste their time with submissions that will need lots of obvious revisions.

An different reason to prefer arxiv is that it offers the source code and HTML versions of the paper, which some people may prefer over the PDF. In particular, I'm told this can be important for accessibility -- e.g. people with impaired vision. However, I don't think that it's appropriate for reviewers to read a different version of the paper than what was submitted.

I guess some percentage of rushed submissions are inescapable when submission deadlines are commonplace, so I'm not sure adding a requirement to submitting to arXiv by the same deadline would help all that much.

The notion that it is a mark of quality is so very field specific that your answer should be edited to reflect that. In my areas, there are two main uses for arxiv - to create a pseudo publication to justify grant renewals while the actual publication is underway, or to provide a bit of protection against getting scooped while you attempt to publish in Nature or Science which can drag out the review processes well over a year. One could equally argue that groups who are confident that the quality of their work is high and will sail through peer review without arxiv is also a mark of quality.

"it supports open science" may be a laudable aim, but since I believe that declining to review non-arXiv'd papers is an ineffective and harmful way to achieve this, I would say this is a poor reason for refusing to review. Maybe some of the disagreement here is because not everyone is making that distinction? (Refusing to review for non-OA journals seems to me to be a route that more directly targets that aim.)

@R1NaNo Yes, many caveats, including Goodhart's law apply. I edited my answer to say it "may" be a mark of quality. I think that's generally true in my area, although it may not be in other areas. And I think it's fine for a reviewer to take that into consideration.

@LouKnee I disagree that "declining to review non-arXiv'd papers is an ineffective and harmful way to" support open science. I'm happy to justify my opinion. But that's not the main point of my answer, so please comment on the appropriate answer.

"There is actually a number of good reasons for doing so. One of them being the apparent lack of faith that authors have in their paper"
This is definitely not a good reason for any subject of interest to the general public (including via public understanding of science), and even more so for policy relevant topics, such as climate science.  In climate science there are plenty of papers that are obviously wrong, but nevertheless get the attention of the public, who don't have the ability to judge whether the argument is sound and the evidence satisfactory.  There is a long history of these papers derailing public debate on climate, and the first two IPCC WG1 reports allude to this in places, in one case naming the paper in question.  Publishing contentious papers on e.g. arXiv is a great way of derailing the public debate with ideas that the author is not confident they could get past proper peer review.
So if you are trying to publish a paper that potentially overturns the current paradigm in some particular topic, then please wait until it has at least passed the minimal hurdle of peer review before promulgating it.  In that case you ought to have a lack of faith in your paper, it is called "self-skepticism", and it should be profound for paradigm overturning claims, because the on the balance of probability, it is you that is wrong, not the mainstream.

This is primarily addressing this answer, but it is representative for many arguments made here and by others.
My arguments are in part similar to Lou Knee’s.
I think most, if not all, answers and arguments I have read for refusing to peer-review manuscripts without preprint fall short in at least one of the following aspects:

They are ultimately about avoiding to review bad papers.
I think the scientific quality of a manuscript (presumed or actual) should not affect the decision to review¹.
Bad papers need to be reviewed too.
If every reviewer employed this attitude, bad papers would end up with reviewers who are overly permissive, failed to spot fundamental problems (e.g. due to lack of expertise), are biased towards the manuscript, etc.
Moreover, such reviewers may suffer from a confirmation bias for those papers they chose to review.
As for manuscripts that are so bad that they should have been desk-rejected, this falls into the journal’s responsibilities.
If I find that I received such a paper for review, I usually leave a friendly comment to the journal that there may be a problem with their process.
If it happens too often, I consider stopping to review for the journal altogether.
Moreover, such papers are quick and easy reviews, so the waste of resources is limited.

They are about things that fall into the journal’s responsibilities and capabilities.
If there is anything suspicious in the manuscript’s history on public record, the journal can detect this at least as well and peer reviewers do not need to bother with this.
I expect that this isn’t worth the time, and the best that can be done is journals noticing authors with streaks of frivolous submissions².
Still, if you think differently, take it to the journals instead of policing it yourself.
One reason for this is that the journal may have more information than what is on public record, e.g., the authors may disclose something to the journal that also explains the absence of a preprint and that reviewers never get to know (and shouldn’t).
Journals ask reviewers to evaluate the quality of the manuscript, not to investigate its potential submission history or similar.
Even if you stumble upon something fishy when reviewing, you should let the journal know instead of drawing silent conclusions.

Preprint availability is used as a proxy for quality or something else.
This requires robust knowledge of the reasons why people don’t publish preprints, which I don’t think anybody has.
In particular, it’s impossible to know all the reasons and thus conclude that at least one of them must apply to somebody not publishing a preprint.
While I don’t claim to know much about author motivations either, I am strongly skeptical of the claim that people do not submit preprints for tactical reasons to hide their frivolous submissions².
In my experience and by Hanlon’s razor, most authors of bad manuscripts are just incompetent.
Moreover, proxy criteria are a dangerous path in general, leading to systemic problems and biases.
Think about other proxy criteria you can use in review such as whether the authors are famous, what country they are from, or the quality of English.

They are assuming the wrong beneficiaries of favours and ethical obligations.
Reviewing is a favour to the journal, not to the authors.
You can choose which journals are worthy of your favour and when, but choosing many other aspects would break the impartiality of peer review.
Likewise, when the journal asks you to review a bad submission that it could have filtered out with reasonable care, it is the journal (not the authors) who is wasting your time and not fulfilling its ethical obligations towards you.
If this happens to an extent that bothers you, stop reviewing for the journal altogether.
The authors who make frivolous submissions² are failing their ethical obligations towards the journal, amongst others because they are harming the journal’s reputation with its reviewers.
The journal is and always should be in the middle.
On a different level, peer review is part of an implicit social contract: You peer-review so you may benefit from peer-review yourself (as an author but also by using peer-reviewed publications).
From this perspective, you have the societal obligation to put a certain amount of energy into peer review.
By choosing presumably easier reviews, you are fulfilling less of this obligation – if all other things remain equal.
Of course, you might compensate by doing more reviews, but that does not seem to be the intention here and also does not solve the other issues.
(I acknowledge that the required and spent energy for peer review are hard to quantify, and unfairness happens for all sorts of reasons, but that doesn’t justify adding more to the pile.)

They fail to comply with the basic ethical standard that one should not act how one does not want others to act (Golden Rule, categorical imperative, etc.):
If everybody reviewed like this, we would have a problem.
I acknowledge that peer review is voluntary, but that doesn’t mean it is without standards.
The journal asks the peer reviewer for a favour, but this favour is not simply peer review, but peer review complying with the journal’s standards and general academic standards for peer review.
The same applies to the reviewer’s obligation within the aforementioned social contract.
Not reviewing papers without preprints currently is not a general standard for peer review (and it cannot be one in the current publishing ecosystem, whether we like that or not).
It is similarly problematic as only reviewing papers from famous authors, friends, certain institutions, etc.



¹ This is a bit different with the quality of writing and similar. Sending back a paper because it’s incomprehensible still furthers the review process.
² By which I mean submissions of manuscripts that the authors know are sub par and expect the reviewers to fix or hope that they fall through the cracks of peer review.

(Given that this question was spawned from comments I made elsewhere, I think I should provide an answer, although many of the reasons have already been touched upon.)
First context: Physical Review D (PRD), the journal in question when the comments were made, primarily publishes papers that are in the fields where the arXiv originated, high energy physics, gravitation, and astrophysics. Correspondingly, many of the sub-fields that publish in PRD belong to the fields that have the highest arXiv adoption rate. So much so, that publication on the arXiv is the primary mode of dissemination for researchers in these fields. Reading the daily arXiv digest in their subfield is part of their morning ritual. Priority on results is established based on the arXiv posts. Publication in a peer reviewed journal (like PRD) is mostly an afterthought, pursued mostly to satisfy the requirements of funding agencies and promotion committees.
In that context, it is reasonable to ask what reasons authors may have to not put a manuscript on the arXiv upon completion, despite this significantly delaying the dissemination the results (and therefore citations and other exposure). Some reasons (some given on this site, others inferred from submissions):

The manuscript is not actually fully finished, but still needs the polish. The authors hope to improve their paper further based on feedback from the reviewers before sharing it more widely. Reviewers are not copy-editors, and trying to use them as such in an unethical waste of their precious time.

The authors are unsure that their paper will pass peer review, and are afraid a lengthy presence on the arXiv may reflect badly on their paper when resubmitting it elsewhere. It is worth pointing out the bar for acceptance in PRD is not exceptionally high. Having a result that is correct and somewhat novel (and on topic), and is well written, is usually enough. I'd suggest that if authors are not confident in meeting this low bar that means that paper is not ready for peer review and needs additional polish.

(The more cynical version of 2.) The authors know their paper is crap, and are planning to shop it around different journals until it slips through the peer review cracks. By not posting it on arXiv, they hope to make their scheme less obvious.

The authors hope to boost their publication statistics by throwing a large volume of low quality manuscripts at peer review, and seeing what sticks. By only posting the accepted manuscripts to arXiv they are avoiding all their failed manuscripts showing up in their public records.

Elsewhere in this thread it was suggested: "not everyone has is easy access to arxiv endorsement" The only context for publication in PRD where this might be applicable is if someone does not have an academic advisor in the field. We are then squarely in Why does independent research from people without formal academic qualifications generally turn out to be a complete waste of time? territory.

The results of the paper are under a NDA. When this is the case this is usually obvious. (And forms an exception to the rest of this narrative.)


None of these reasons bode particularly well for the quality of the work, and many suggest the authors are wasting reviewer time. Given that as a reviewer, time is usually scarce, and there are many more review requests than one can accept, it is reasonable for reviewers to triage review requests on the basis of what is most worth their time by declining to review those manuscripts which the authors apparently do not think are worth the light of day. Doubly, so since the reasons above tend to point to lengthy review processes with several resubmissions before final acceptance/rejection.
Note that this is not saying that these manuscripts should be rejected, just that a particular reviewer is not wasting their time on them. This may, of course, delay the peer review process, but since the authors were already willing to delay dissemination they can't be too much in a hurry.
Besides these concerns about quality (and apparent effort of the authors) there are practical factors:

The first and foremost is that a preprint being available makes the manuscript citeable. It is inevitable (especially in theoretical fields) that thorough peer review of a work leads to inspiration on alternative lines of inquiry. Any works coming from this probably need to cite the work that inspired it. This becomes problematic if the original work ends up rejected, and is never published. Having a preprint available shields the reviewer from any such ethical awkwardness.

In the case that the journal does not make the full text of a manuscript available to a reviewer before making a decision whether to accept the review , this allows the reviewer to know what they are getting themselves into before accepting to review that 80 page manuscript. (This is not applicable to PRD, since they do always provide access before making a decision.)

Having a preprint on arXiv available, allows the reviewer to see the (public) version history of the manuscript. Most of the time this does not matter, but can be useful when the reviewer suspects the manuscript is being shopped around.


I will re-iterate that most of the sentiment above, only makes sense in the context of a field where posting on the arXiv is the de facto standard way of making results public. In the context of fields where arXiv adoption is less standard, only some of it makes sense, but there appear many more "not so bad" reasons for not posting to the arXiv.

Thank you for posting this. In regards to 5, it struck me a couple days ago that the fields represented in PRD might also be overrepresented among crackpots.

I would be ok with this iff PRD lists posting on the arvix as a requirement.  Otherwise, this is a barrier from outsiders publishing in this journals.  Not all outsiders are cranks.  Some are chemists.  Some are mathematicians.  This sort of hidden rule is another barrier to people doing work in other areas.

@TerryLoring That would be an issue only if all reviewers do this.

@TimRias: … and hence it is unethical by the arguably most commonly accepted standard of ethics.

@Wrzlprmft this passes the golden rule with flying colors.

@TimRias: As you noted yourself, if all reviewers behaved like you (presumably), this would be an issue. I assume you do not want this to happen. That violates the principle: “Do not behave like you do not want others to behave.” (At this point we might argue whether this is to be categorised as the Golden Rule, the categorical imperative, or something other fundamental ethical paradigm, but that’s not the point here.)

I posted an answer that to a large extent addresses points made in this answer.

The results of the paper are under a NDA. When this is the case this is usually obvious. – I am not in a research area, where NDAs are common, so I have never (knowingly) seen such a paper. However, I would assume that when the authors submit such a paper for review, the manuscript going through peer review and being published is fine by the NDA. As the peer-reviewers themselves are bound by a sort of NDA, there seems to be no reason to inform them about it. Moreover, I see no reason to put this into the manuscript itself. So, how could you tell as a reviewer?

I have seen #3 in action, and it is v unpleasant to witness the author's later success

Probably my answer has a lot in common with the answer of @LouKnee above. But I have a slightly different justification.
It took me a while even to understand the point. In my mind I simply cannot connect conditioning of a review to the fact that the manuscript is or is not submitted elsewhere. No publisher puts such a formal requirement on the author and on the reviewer to check it.
But you can review the manuscript and reject it because the authors fail to provide data supporting their findings. Arxiv can be a good (but not the only one possible) value to share such information. Zenodo would be an alternative.
Concerning the open science that some answers emphasise. Arxiv is not the only way to do open science. There are many options depending on the budget of authors. For instance, they can pay to publisher to make their work open access. Notice, this can be done even after publication.
I strongly oppose to the statement that putting a manuscript on arxiv is a mark of quality. The opinion of referee should be based on scientific facts and not on some indirect indicators. And yes, if the referee cannot decide and uses this fact as the only criterion---it is unethical.

Arguably, arXiv overlay journals do put such a requirement on their authors. But then the submission to the journal is essentially just linking to the preprint.

@Anyon This is new to me. I know that in, for example, APS journals such a possibility exists, but it is never mandated. ACS and IOP journals do not even provide this as a possibility. Can you please provide the source of your information?

I don't think any of the more established publishers do this. APS does indeed have some function for pulling files from arXiv, but that's different. What I meant is something like is described here  https://discreteanalysisjournal.com/for-authors I think it's more common in CS.

@Anyon Thank you, I really learnt something new today. I never heard of such journals before.

If a paper is on arXiv (or otherwise publicly available) a prospective reviewer can look at it and decide if they want to invest their time into it. An experienced reviewer can quickly get a sense of how easy (or not) they will find it to review the manuscript, and assess whether they feel they can add value proportionate to the time required.

I do like having a look at a paper before agreeing to review it, but per Note 2 in the question, I think it's unlikely to be a big factor in the case of APS journals. I find that clicking on the link in the invitation email, having the browser autofill password, and then clicking to open the PDF is at least as fast as trying to locate a public preprint by authors and title (that might not perfectly match the preprint version, if one exists).

If everyone did this, imagine how double-blind peer review would work ...
